# Data Tables- Json data could not be parsed in Symfony2

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, symfony, datatables

I keep getting this error:

DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error.

I'm not sure what the problem is. Is the routing that is incorrect? I verified the json file that is generated with http://jsonlint.com/ at it is valid.

Controller:
     public function indexAction($id)
     {

```
    return $this-render('CetiucValidateSurveyBundle:Validate:validatespreadsheet.html.twig');



}
```

The twig(view) file that has the javascript and the table.

validatespreadsheet.html.twig':

```
<table id="myDataTable" >
   <thead>
   <tr>
       <th>Company name</th>
       <th>Address</th>
       <th>Town</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>



   </tbody>
```

the javascript for retrieving data for the table from the controller:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myDataTable').dataTable(

            {
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "{{ path('CetiucValidateSurveyBundle_renderJson')}}"
            }

    );

});
```

The method in the controller for returning the data to the view

```
public function renderJsonAction(Request $request)
{


    $arr = array ('aaData' => array(
        array('3','35','4', '$14,500', '$15,200','$16,900','5','1'),
        array('1','16','4', '$14,200', '$15,100','$14,900','Running','1'),
        array('5','25','4', '$14,500', '$15,600','$16,900','Not Running','1')
    )
    );

    $post_data = json_encode($arr);

    return new Response( $post_data,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type

}
```

This is the routing entry for the action returning the json

```
CetiucValidateSurveyBundle_renderJson:
   defaults: { _controller: "CetiucValidateSurveyBundle:Validate:renderJson" }
   pattern:   /json
   requirements: { _method: POST }
```

Comment: If go to app_dev.php/validator/json I get the correct Json {"aaData":[["3","35","4","$14,500","$15,200","$16,900","5","1"],["1","16","4","$‌​14,200","$15,100","$14,900","Running","1"],["5","25","4","$14,500","$15,600","$16‌​,900","Not Running","1"]]} But I still get the same error when I try to get this Json with Ajax in the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use

```
requirements: { _method: POST }
```

Also, are you sure you want to use `bServerSide = true`?

Comment: I'm not sure what bServerSide = true means, I want to obtain the data to be displayed in the data tables from the controller (sent by a json file). Thanks!

Comment: it means that all processing is handled server side, which I don't think you need. See http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Comment: But if i want to retrieve data from the "sAjaxSource" I chose that points to an action in my controler, I do have to indlude bServerSide=true, or not?

Comment: Have you read the link I just added? You want to get the data from the server, but not process everything (pagination, sorting, etc...) on the server side

Comment: I still have get the same error after deleted the POST-requierenments and taking away the bserverside= true :S

Comment: If you ask for the /json url, do you get the JSON data?

Comment: I had a problem with my routing, and I corrected it. Now if I go to app_dev.php/validator/json I get the correct Json {"aaData":[["3","35","4","$14,500","$15,200","$16,900","5","1"],["1","16","4","$14,200","$15,100","$14,900","Running","1"],["5","25","4","$14,500","$15,600","$16,900","Not Running","1"]]}
But I still get the same error when I try to get this Json with Ajax in the view.

Comment: Have you checked what is output in your twig template?

Comment: It worked, thanks Carlos. I think I had problems with the routing. After trying all that you recommended it worked.